# Hudson/Jenkins - Run steps in master and slave under the same job

Tags: hudson, master-slave

I have a master and slave machines and one job.
This job should have two steps: One to run Unit tests on the master machine
and the other to run some executable laying in the slave machine.

Can this be done under one job? I know that I can restrict the job to run in slave only
but i couldn't find a way to restrict in the step level.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i know you can only bind a job to a particular node but not parts of the job.

Comment: If so, then do you know if Hudson has a way to run two jobs and show their results in one report?

Comment: What you can do is to produce the report results into a folder which is outside the workspace of Hudson and pickup the information by an other job to produce the report from it (can be done by down-stream/up-stream dependency).